# Triangle inequality for the Hilbert-Schmidt matrix norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to prove the triangle inequality for the Hilbert-Schmidt norm defined as

$$\|A\|_{HS}=\text{tr}((A^\star A))^\frac{1}{2}$$

for some $m\times n$ matrix $A$ of complex-valued indices.

So far, I have been guided this far by my professor

$$\|A\|_{H S}=\left(\operatorname{tr}\left(A^{*} A\right)\right)^{1 / 2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left[\sum_{j=1}^{n} \overline{a_{i j}} a_{i j}\right]\right)^{1 / 2}=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{m} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\left|a_{i j}\right|^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

How can I use this to show $\|A+B\|_{HS}\le\|A\|_{HS}+\|B\|_{HS}$?

Comment: Use the triangle inequality for the usual norm on $\mathbb{C}^n$ (there is a square missing in your computation).

Comment: @operatorerror But wouldn't the usual norm have $a_{ii}^2$?

Comment: $a\overline{a}=|a|^2$

Comment: @operatorerror Ah thank you so much

Comment: $\|A+B\|_{H S}=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i i}+b_{i i}|^{2}}$
$\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|a_{i i}|^{2}}+\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left|b_{i i}\right|^{2}}$
$=\|A\|_{H S}+\|B\|_{H S}$  @operatorerror Is this correct/

Comment: there's a modulus missing in the first expression but looks good otherwise